# jq parsing get value

Tags: json, linux, jq

I need to get some values from a json file. I need to get a array (dimmer1, dimmer2)

Somebody any idea?

```
{
 "devices": {
    "dimmer1": {
      "protocol": ["kaku_dimmer"],
      "state": "off",
      "dimlevel": 1
    },
    "dimmer2": {
      "protocol": ["kaku_dimmer"],
      "state": "off",
      "dimlevel": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? `jq` has a manual, tutorials, ...

Comment: When u use something like jq .devices you can only get the value after the : not the "name" of the value like dimmer1 or state

Comment: When you parse this`JSON` you will have a multidimensional array or object based on the parser. The values you want (`dimmer1`, `dimmer2`) are keys not values so they are identifying your values and are not values themselves, they are **keys**. You can iterate over the array and request the keys also but there is no way to accurately retrieve the keys of an array.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**EDIT:** After clarification in the comments, to retrieve the states of devices whose key begins with "dimmer", use

```
jq '[ .devices | to_entries[] | select(.key | startswith("dimmer")) | .value = .value.state ] | from_entries' filename.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "dimmer1": "off",
  "dimmer2": "off"
}
```

This works as follows:

- `.devices` selects the `.devices` attribute of the JSON object
- `to_entries` explodes the object into an array of key-value pairs describing its attributes (the devices), which is to say that an attribute `"foo": "bar"` becomes an object `{ "key": "foo", "value": "bar" }`, and the exploded object is expanded into an array of such objects (one for each attribute)
- `to_entries[]` unpacks that array, in order to pipe it through
- `select(.key | startswith("dimmer"))`, which selects of the devices those whose key begins with `dimmer`
- `.value = .value.state` restructures the key-value pair that describes the device so that the value is replaced with just its `state` attribute
- `[ all that ]` makes a JSON array of all that, and
- `[ all that ] | from_entries` converts the array of key-value pairs back to JSON objects.

#### Old answer (shortened), now obsolete but possibly of interest:

To retrieve the keys of the attributes of `devices` in an array:

```
jq '.devices | keys' filename.json
```

To retrieve the values (also in an array),

```
jq '[ .devices[] ]' filename.json
```

I wasn't entirely sure which of those two you meant.

Comment: i thought it was helping but its only making it harder.

I need to get all the states from the devices that start with dimmer* something like this

dimmer1, on
dimmer2, off

Comment: You know, if that's what you wanted to achieve, you could have mentioned that in the question. In fact, you should edit the question to make it clear that this is what you wanted. Anyway, see the edit.